# UIImagePickerController Cropping?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

I have read that it is automatic but it doesn't appear to be happening in my case. Using UIImagePickerController with allowsEditing set to YES I get my editing view with the crop square overlay, but when i am finished with the image its not cropped as I expect.

Should it be automatic at this stage? If not, what might be a good solution to crop the image in the matching area that the default view provides?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong key for the info dictionary: `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`.
To get the cropped (yes, it is automatic) image you have to use `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` key.

This should do the trick:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *pickedImageEdited = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    //dismiss the picker and process the image...
}
```