# UIImage won't crop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

The user takes a photo using with the camera (`UIImagePickerController`). However, I can't crop it - or I try, and it returns the exact same photo.

In `viewDidAppear`I create the image picker controller:

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.delegate = self;

    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    ipc.showsCameraControls = NO;

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SnapItCameraView" owner:self options:nil];
    self.overlayView.frame = ipc.cameraOverlayView.frame;
    ipc.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
    self.overlayView = nil;
    CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 71.0); 
    ipc.cameraViewTransform = translate;
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    CGFloat scaleCamera = screenHeight / 426;

    CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, scaleCamera, scaleCamera);
    ipc.cameraViewTransform = scale;
    ipc.showsCameraControls = NO;
    ipc.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
    ipc.allowsEditing = YES;
    [ipc setAllowsEditing:YES];

    [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

```
UIImage* theImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage, nil, nil, nil);             
[self ordinaryCrop:theImage toRect:CGRectMake(20, 0, 250, 250)];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Cropping:

```
-(UIImage *)ordinaryCrop:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)cropRect
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], cropRect);
    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return cropped;
}
```

But the image is exactly the same after cropping it. I tried the solution [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281099/uiimagepickercontroller-cropping), but
    `UIImage* theImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];` returns nil

```
It's different from [this post][2] because, as the bounty answer points out,
```

"The AllowsEditing property simply allows the user to crop to a square if picking an image." The user is not picking an image, and I am not trying to crop to a square specifically. I am trying to crop it at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController AllowsEditing not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024648/uiimagepickercontroller-allowsediting-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return `cropped` from your `ordinaryCrop` function but you don't do anything with it in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, you simply save the original image again.

What you want is:

```
UIImage* theImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage, nil, nil, nil);             
UIImage *croppedImage = [self ordinaryCrop:theImage toRect:CGRectMake(20, 0, 250, 250)];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Take a UIButton and try this:**

**1.**

```
 UIButton *addImage_Button;
```

**2.**

```
-(IBAction)addImage_Button:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES; //THIS IS FOR CROPPING
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

**3.**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *chosenUserImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    chosenUserImage = [chosenUserImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    addImage_Button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [addImage_Button setImage:chosenUserImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

**4.**

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```